# Prob with buildozer apk and custom python package

Tags: android, python, package, kivy, buildozer

Is anyone can run this code on android with buildozer compilation :

(for me, it compiles, but crash on android)

.../main.py

```
__version__ = '0.1'

from code.app import MyApp

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    MyApp().run()
```

.../code/__init__.py

```
nothing
```

.../code/app.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

```
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello !')
```

.../buildozer.spec

```
[app]

title = Test
package.name = myTest
package.domain = org.test
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py
version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py
requirements = kivy
orientation = portrait
fullscreen = 1

[buildozer]
log_level = 1
warn_on_root = 1
```

adb logcat : (extract)

D/OpenGLRenderer( 9422): Enabling debug mode 0
V/WindowManager(  857): Adding window Window{2584f44 u0 SurfaceView} at 3 of 11 (before Window{fdf5dd6 u0 org.test.myloging/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity})
I/SDLSurface( 9422): Choose egl configuration
I/SDLSurface( 9422): Try to use graphics config R8G8B8A8S8
W/SDLSurface( 9422): Create egl surface
I/python  ( 9422): presplash-fit is null
I/ActivityManager(  857): Displayed   org.test.myloging/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity: +218ms
I/python  ( 9422): presplash (fit=null) mx=0,703125,my=1,156250
I/libSDL  ( 9422): Physical screen resolution is 720x1184
I/python  ( 9422): Initialize Python for Android
W/InputMethodManager( 9422): Ignoring onBind: cur seq=1016, given seq=1015
I/Timeline( 9422): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@22de304a time:52888036
I/python  ( 9422): ['/data/data/org.test.myloging/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/org.test.myloging/files/lib/site-python']
I/python  ( 9422): Android path ['/data/data/org.test.myloging/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/data/org.test.myloging/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/data/org.test.myloging/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/data/org.test.myloging/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/org.test.myloging/files', '/data/data/org.test.myloging/files/_applibs']
I/python  ( 9422): Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
I/python  ( 9422): Run user program, change dir and execute main.py
I/python  ( 9422): Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  ( 9422):   File "/home/romuald/Kivy/Login/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 4, in 
I/python  ( 9422): ImportError: No module named app
I/python  ( 9422): Python for android ended.
I/art     ( 9422): System.exit called, status: 0
I/AndroidRuntime( 9422): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
I/WindowState(  857): WIN DEATH: Window{fdf5dd6 u0 org.test.myloging/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
I/WindowState(  857): WIN DEATH: Window{2584f44 u0 SurfaceView}
I/ActivityManager(  857): Process org.test.myloging:python (pid 9422) has died
W/ActivityManager(  857): Force removing ActivityRecord{250b9f13 u0 org.test.myloging/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity t170}: app died, no saved state

Comment: Use adb logcat to see the crash message.

Comment: there seems to be a prob with an absolute path which should not exist after compiling File "/home/romuald/Kivy/Login/.buildozer/android/app/main.py". This is generated by buildozer. What can I do ?

Comment: I have no idea why it crashes, but if you place MyApp in main.py file without importing it, it is going to work.

Comment: Of course, but i created this example only to reduce a prob with a fatter app.

Comment: In my projects, I put majority of the app logic into custom widgets, so they can be imported from separate files. This way, the App class in very small. You could also try setting `source.dir` property in buildozer.spec file.